# In Nginx, can I have TLSv1/1.1/1.2 for hosts on local network but only TLSv1.1/1.2 to all others?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a server that I want to have TLSv1 disabled for all connecting hosts except those on the local network.

Currently, my nginx conf looks like this:

```
server {
  listen                *:443 default_server ssl;
  server_name           myhostname;
  ...
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ...
}

server {
  listen                *:443 default_server ssl;
  server_name           myhostname;
  ...
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ...

  location / {
      allow 10.0.0.0/8;
      deny all;
      ...
  }
}
```

I want to allow only 10.0.0.0/8 hosts to use TLSv1 but this configuration is giving me a warning that there is a duplicate with myhostname at port 443.

I am testing this with

```
openssl s_client -connect myhostname.com:443 -tls1
```

and does not seem like it is working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use geo directives of nginx.
[this will help you to understand geo directive batter](https://serverfault.com/questions/743414/how-can-i-check-if-remote-addr-ip-is-not-in-cidr-range-in-nginx)

```
http{
..
geo $allow_all_ssl {
    default         0;
    10.0.0.0/8      1;
}
..}
server{
...
set $ssl_value "TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2";
if ($allow_all_ssl) {
set $ssl_value "TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2";
}
ssl_protocols $ssl_value;
```